# Is -Duser.language option is a VM property

Tags: java

I am confused of passing `-Duser.language` option. we can pull this in our application by just calling `System.getProperty("user.language)`, But if we set the `Locale.setDefault()` to some other language, will it override the user.language which we passed as vm args.
And even if i set the `System.setProperty("user.language","someotherlang")`, does it overrides `user.language` which we passed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all options that you pass to the JVM with `-D...` are called *system properties*. As you know, you can access them with `System.getProperty(...)`. You are even allowed (if not having a restrictive security manager) to change these properties by adding, removing, and changing the key-value-pairs.

Regarding the locale settings, have a look at the interesting parts of `Locale`'s implementation (JDK8):

```
public final class Locale implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    [...]
    private volatile static Locale defaultLocale = initDefault();
    [...]
    private static Locale initDefault() {
        String language, region, script, country, variant;
        language = AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("user.language", "en"));
        [...] // here other properties are also retrieved
        return getInstance(language, script, country, variant, null);
    }
    [...]
}
```

So, the first time the class `Locale` is accessed, it is also initialized, which also means an initialization of the static variable `defaultLocale` with respect to the above mentioned system property.

If you later change one of these system properties ("user.language" for example) this will not have any effect to the private class variable `defaultLocale`.

On the other hand, you can (re)set the *default locale* with calling `Locale.setDefault(...)`. Let's have a look into its implementation:

```
public static synchronized void setDefault(Locale newLocale) {
    setDefault(Category.DISPLAY, newLocale);
    setDefault(Category.FORMAT, newLocale);
    defaultLocale = newLocale;
}
```

This calls the other setting method, so let's have a look there also:

```
public static synchronized void setDefault(Locale.Category category, Locale newLocale) {
    [...]
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) sm.checkPermission(new PropertyPermission("user.language", "write"));
    switch (category) {
    case DISPLAY: defaultDisplayLocale = newLocale; break;
    case FORMAT: defaultFormatLocale = newLocale; break;
    default: assert false: "Unknown Category";
    }
}
```

As you can see, the private class variable `defaulLocale` is set to the new locale you want to set, but the system property "user.language" is not touched.

That means, the system properties regarding the locale are used for initialization, and then they are not interesting anymore.

In fact, this is some standard behavior for configuring an application. Even I use this mechanism: Reading system properties for initializing my components (using some default if the system property is not set), but then not touching the system properties anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Seelenvirtuose, It has clarified my doubt.